# How to solve a linear programming which the objective function is series

Tags: optimization, dynamic, model, sum, include

I want to optimize a linear program which consists of **8760 sets of hourly Lp models** for example:

```
AEC=sumation1:8760 Ech
Ech=480x1+333x2-140x3
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail. Also please explain what you have sone so far to solve this preoblem.  If this isnt a preomgramming issue but only mathematics then you are on the wrong site.

Comment: I want to optimize a linear program  in matlab which has a objective function named Ech. indeed  our real objective function is sumation of this Ech from 1 to 8760.my question  is how can i  do that in matlab ? do i have  to use for function ? if yes! how can i do that?!

Comment: Our problem include 3 constraint and 5 sign restriction. Constraint: x1is less and eqaul 350.

Comment: I fear, SO is the wrong place if you look into the search you will not find a lot of answers. So it seems you will not find the right people here for answering your question. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab